# Initialising MockMvc through Mockito

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm having some trouble trying to get MockMvc to run with Mockito. This is what I have so far:

```
public class mockito {

MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
EntryController controller;

@Mock 
DAO data_access_object;

SmokeEvent evt = new SmokeEvent(18);

@Before
public void setup() {

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).build(); 
//Exception thrown at above line (line 44) when the build method is called

}
@Test
public void viewRendersCorrectly() throws Exception
{
    /**
     * This test method is supposed to check to see if the controller renders
     * correctly
     */
when(data_access_object.getEvent(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(evt);
}

}
```

The following is the stack trace it throws in Testing mode. I should also state that I've been working through the Spring REST tutorial over at spring.io

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:721)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.<clinit>(GenericServlet.java:95)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilderSupport.createMockMvc(MockMvcBuilderSupport.java:50)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.build(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:193)
at test.mockito.setup(mockito.java:44)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running a standalone test, you need to create an instance of `EntryController` for `standaloneSetup()` method. As it is, you're passing standaloneSetup a null reference.

The other option is to run a semi-integrated test with `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup` and an appropriate `WebApplicationContext`.

for example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {yourconfigurationClasses.class})
public class ... {

    @Inject 
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void beforeSetUp() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
```